# Remove first folder names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I delete the first 4 folders names using batch script?
 The result should be the last 4 folders path.

```
C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06
```

Should be like this
 `Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06`

Comment: Do you know the part to remove (`C:\Test\Test01\Test02\`) in advance or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06"
    for /f "tokens=4,* delims=\" %%a in ("%folder%") do echo %%b
```

The `for /f` tokenizes the indicated string using backslash as delimiter. We request the fourth token (the last discarded one) that will be stored in `%%a`, and the rest of the line (`*`) that will be stored in `%%b`

```
                  C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06
delimiters          ^    ^      ^      ^
tokens            1  2    3      4      *
```